# is "LocationListener.onLocationChanged" method is better than any other way of getting Location

Tags: android, locationlistener, battery-saver

1. is `LocationListener.onLocationChanged` method is better than any other way of getting Location.
2. if so is there a better way to use it, so as to get better battery performance.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know of an alternative to `LocationListener.onLocationChanged` , maybe you can yourself shed some light on this ?

As for the battery issue, you can call  `requestLocationUpdates()`  just less often to avoid battery draining. 
This call for this contains a variable `minDistance` (in milliseconds), you should use this one. Please note that observing minDistance was *not* mandatory until android 4.3 .

For devices with versions prior to 4.3 , you need to

1) stop calling updates in **onLocationChanged**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
}
```

2) override the method run to introduce a new interval.

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    // getting location...
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
    // ...once per hour
    mHandler.postDelayed(onRequestLocation, DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

For further reference , see the docu for [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)